# How to add a new keyboard layout to Emacs input methods?

Tags: input-method

I've downloaded a new layout from https://qwerty-lafayette.org/ which I would like to use. However I am struggling to understand how I can use it inside Emacs. Usually I set languages by using `(set-input-method "language")`.
However here I can't select the language, how can I do this for this particular language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's not much documentation for the quail / leim stuff in Emacs; but once you know where to look, you can generally muddle your way through based on existing cases (there are so many of them, that there's generally likely to be something similar to use as a basis).

See <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `leim-list` for all of the `register-input-method` calls.  To pick an example with a keyboard layout:

```el
(register-input-method
 "english-dvorak" "English" 'quail-use-package
 "DV@" "English (ASCII) input method simulating Dvorak keyboard"
 "quail/latin-post")
```

The following is then a verbatim quote of the `english-dvorak` input method and keyboard layout from that `quail/latin-post` library.  I believe that the call to `quail-define-rules` is automatically using the most-recent `quail-define-package` declaration, so this is pretty much all there is.

Note that you can visit that library with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `quail/latin-post` (type it verbatim; completion won't complete it), and of course the many other files in the same directory provide other different examples.

Checking your link, I guess the better examples to look at are the `french-keyboard` and `french-azerty` input methods (which are also in `latin-post.el`).  Once you have this working, perhaps you could contribute it upstream alongside those?

```el
(require 'quail)

(quail-define-package
 "english-dvorak" "English" "DV@" t
 "English (ASCII) input method simulating Dvorak keyboard"
 nil t t t t nil nil nil nil nil t)

;; 1!  2@  3#  4$  5%  6^  7&  8*  9(  0)  [{  ]}  `~
;;  '"  ,<  .>  pP  yY  fF  gG  cC  rR  lL  /?  =+
;;   aA  oO  eE  uU  iI  dD  hH  tT  nN  sS  -_  \|
;;    ;:  qQ  jJ  kK  xX  bB  mM  wW  vV  zZ

(quail-define-rules
 ("-" ?\[)
 ("=" ?\])
 ("`" ?`)
 ("q" ?')
 ("w" ?,)
 ("e" ?.)
 ("r" ?p)
 ("t" ?y)
 ("y" ?f)
 ("u" ?g)
 ("i" ?c)
 ("o" ?r)
 ("p" ?l)
 ("[" ?/)
 ("]" ?=)
 ("a" ?a)
 ("s" ?o)
 ("d" ?e)
 ("f" ?u)
 ("g" ?i)
 ("h" ?d)
 ("j" ?h)
 ("k" ?t)
 ("l" ?n)
 (";" ?s)
 ("'" ?-)
 ("\\" ?\\)
 ("z" ?\;)
 ("x" ?q)
 ("c" ?j)
 ("v" ?k)
 ("b" ?x)
 ("n" ?b)
 ("m" ?m)
 ("," ?w)
 ("." ?v)
 ("/" ?z)

 ("_" ?{)
 ("+" ?})
 ("~" ?~)
 ("Q" ?\")
 ("W" ?<)
 ("E" ?>)
 ("R" ?P)
 ("T" ?Y)
 ("Y" ?F)
 ("U" ?G)
 ("I" ?C)
 ("O" ?R)
 ("P" ?L)
 ("{" ??)
 ("}" ?+)
 ("A" ?A)
 ("S" ?O)
 ("D" ?E)
 ("F" ?U)
 ("G" ?I)
 ("H" ?D)
 ("J" ?H)
 ("K" ?T)
 ("L" ?N)
 (":" ?S)
 ("\"" ?_)
 ("|" ?|)
 ("Z" ?:)
 ("X" ?Q)
 ("C" ?J)
 ("V" ?K)
 ("B" ?X)
 ("N" ?B)
 ("M" ?M)
 ("<" ?W)
 (">" ?V)
 ("?" ?Z)
 )
```

---

For a minimal example of a layout which switches the "f" and "o" characters, you could put this in your init file:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))

(register-input-method
 "foo" "French" 'quail-use-package
 "FOO@" "Example input method"
 "foo-input-method")
```

And create a file `~/.emacs.d/lisp/foo-input-method.el` containing:

```el
(require 'quail)

(quail-define-package
 "foo" "Foo" "Foo" t
 "Example input method"
 nil t t t t nil nil nil nil nil t)

(quail-define-rules
 ("F" ?O)
 ("f" ?o)
 ("O" ?F)
 ("o" ?f)
 )

(provide 'foo-input-method)
```

Comment: Ok, if I understood you correctly all the keyboard definitions are found in latin-post.el and I would have to change it manually and add this french-lafayette layout? (For me the file by the way is named leim/qual/latin-post.el.gz).

I will think about adding additional french keyboard definition if I will have time, but since I haven't contributed anything until now, I probably won't find the energy to figure out how this contribution thing is working.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` will provide an email template you can use for sending in a feature request.

Comment: If you're just doing it for yourself, though, you can add the code to your init file, or to any other file that you load.