# How can I use Canadian CSA keyboard layout in Emacs on Windows WSL

Tags: input-method, keyboard-layout, wsl

Following the questions [How to use a certain keyboard layout from emacs as Ubuntu keyboard layout](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/how-to-use-a-certain-keyboard-layout-from-emacs-as-ubuntu-keyboard-layout) and [How to add a new keyboard layout to Emacs input methods?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69729/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-to-emacs-input-methods)
I need help for a concrete example - I want to use the Canadian CSA keyboard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSA_keyboard (also available on Mac as a layout option) as an input method for emacs on Windows with WSL. The second answer in the second question is insufficient here, since there exists a lot of combination keys which I don't know how to incorporate, for example ¨ following some letter or ^ following some letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your OS to the keyboard layout you want. No need to mess with Emacs settings.

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to do it, I need to change it on linux virtual environment. I don't know how to find this aforementioned canadian csa layout there

Comment: This really isn’t the right place to ask for help with Windows. You could start here: https://lmgtfy.app/?q=change+windows+keyboard+layout

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with Windows as Emacs is running on Ubuntu environment, but agreed, I should ask it on Ubuntu forum then